# Xcode I Tableview viewItemWithTag cannot cast from UITableViewCell to UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

That's the cellForRowAtIndexPath function. I want to set the cell's UIImageView child's photo, but I cannot create the outlet for that. It crashes saying:

> Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x22d3e0f40) to 'UIImageView' (0x22d3e5810)

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath)    
let profileImageView = cell.viewWithTag(0) as! UIImageView 
return cell
```

Comment: Have you assigned a tag to your `UIImageView` and it should be 1.

Comment: Oh, I left it as 0. Thanks. I thought it can be the default value.

Answer (score 1):

Every view have by default tag `0` so you need to give tag `1` to your `UIImageView` from storyboard and then you need to replace

```
let profileImageView = cell.viewWithTag(0) as! UIImageView
```

with

```
 let profileImageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution is to create a custom cell class that provides a property for the `UIImageView` that you can access directly.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell // use your actual class name
let profileImageView = cell.imageView // access the custom cell's image view property
```

Your code doesn't work because all views have a tag of 0 by default.